# IP address returning two values and need to check if in IPv4 format

Tags: node.js

I am retrieving an IP address like this:

```
const ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || 
                req.connection.remoteAddress || 
                req.socket.remoteAddress ||
                (req.connection.socket ? req.connection.socket.remoteAddress : null)
```

However, this is giving me the IP address in the format:

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, XX.XX.X.XXX
```

I don't know why it's giving me two addresses, I only want the first one. Also I need to be able to detect whether the IP address is in IPv4 format or not.

How can I do this?

Comment: It's likely the format of `x-forwarded-for` you're seeing

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Thanks that was it, I've just taken the first substring separated by a comma now. How can I check it's in IPv4 format?

Comment: use Addr#kind() from ipaddr.js you will find this in here https://github.com/joyent/node-ip6addr